# Why should define('RELOCATE',true) be removed from wordpress config?

Tags: wordpress, release, deployment, production

It seems that using the [define('RELOCATE')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) command is a convenient tool to perform site development using a local database and webserver, then to upload into production.  Otherwise, its necessary to perform SQL REPLACE commands to update all the URLs in the posts, media and other content.

The Wordpress codex specifically states that it must be removed, but occasionally after removing, the links revert back to the dev server.  Is there a reason for removal? it doesn't seem that security should be the issue, perhaps performance?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

The reason you remove it is because `define('RELOCATE',true);` will point every visitor of your site to the admin login.

If you are still getting re-directed to the dev server then you need to re-configure your database.

Comment: I don't see this behaviour.  No redirects are being performed.  What needs to be reconfigured in the db?